# The Physics behind 2D Platformer Games?

Tags: 2d, game-design, physics, platformer

Is there any good book or tutorial that explains the physics behind creating a 2D Platformer game? Such as tile rendering, tile map reading, collision detection, camera movement etc.?

Comment: Wait, what does rendering and camera movement have to do with physics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a character jump?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29617/how-to-make-a-character-jump)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I stumbled upon this link here on gamedev and I really found it enlighting.

http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/

It explains some basic methods of implementing tile based levels, but there are also some important parts about how certain mechanics work in 2d platformers. I think you should look into slopes, as they can solve many problems you come across in platformers.

Good to know is, that most platformers don't even bother with implementing proper physics, but implement certain rules, that mimic some physical behavior (like gravity), but allow certain behaviors that wouldn't be allowed with proper physics (air control for example).

Comment: Link is dead, but found a mirror on the WB http://web.archive.org/web/20150214064910/http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/ and saved a modified copy http://tankorsmash.com/platformer_mirror/